# Display Table By Price with Jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting, filter, html-table

I'm trying to display only the rows that meet the condition, but I seem to be hiding everything with my current solution. Does anyone have an idea of what might be going wrong here, and how to fix it?

```js
var rangeOne = "col2.alpha";

$("button.priceRangeOne").click(function(){  
    if ($(rangeOne < 500)) {
       $("tr").css("display","none");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="priceRangeOne">$0-$499</button>

<table>
    <tr class="row1 tv">
        <td class="col1 alpha">Samsung</td>
        <td class="col2 alpha">$499</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row2 tv">
        <td class="col1 alpha">Vizio</td>
        <td class="col2 alpha">$500</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$(rangeOne < 500)` is something very strange.

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna there is `var rangeOne = "alpha";` three lines above this variable's usage.

Comment: Yes, but then what is meant by this? $(rangeOne < 500)

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna it is bad knowledge of jQuery :) It is about comparing `$(".alpha")` elements text number with 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : You can find all `td` with class="alpha" and then iterate them to compare amount in it.

```
var rangeOne = "alpha";
$("button.priceRangeOne").click(function(){
    //find all alpha tds  
    $("."+rangeOne).each(function(){
       // remove $ sign
       var amount = $(this).html().replace('$','');
       //check if it is amount and compare it
       if(!isNaN(amount) && parseInt(amount) < 500)
         $(this).closest('tr').hide();
    });

});
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pjudvpv8/)**

Comment: @Regent, yeah your suggestion about using `var rangeOne = ".alpha"` is right but I kept it as it is because may be OP has some other usage of it. And for non-amount td I have updated answer with `isNaN()` condition. I appreciate your suggestion, thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome :) Well, yes, it might be that it is used anywhere else, even though I somewhy suspect it won't. But it's OP business, +1.